# How can I still get each line of a text file when the variable is in quotations?

Tags: powershell

I've been messing arround with Powershell and googling various things as I go along. This one is a little hard to put into words that google woule understand. I can get the indevidual lines of a text file in powershell by indexing:

```
$textFile = Get-Content "myText.txt"
$textFile[0]
```

This would output the first line of the text file. But when I put the text file in quotes it will output all lines, even with the index

```
"$textFile[0]"
```

How can I still get only get the line I want, while wrapping the variable in quotes? If I try `"$textFile"[0]` it will just give me the whole file as before. The reason I'm trying to do this is because I'm trying to make that one line of the text file part of a bigger string that I can execute

```
$remote = "Enter-PSSession -ComputerName`", textFile[0]"

Invoke-Expression $remote
```

This is my way of illustrating what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the following methods:

```
# Sub-expression operator
"Some Text $($textFile[0])"

# String format operator
"My Text {0}" -f $textFile[0]

# Concatenation
("Text"+$textFile[0])
```

---

Surrounding double quotes tells PowerShell to expand the string inside. Any variables within will be interpolated. Variables begin with `$` and their following names can only have certain characters without requiring a special escape. `[` would require an escape and since it isn't escaped, PowerShell interprets the variable name ending with the character just before the `[`. Therefore `$textFile` is interpolated, the whole file contents are converted into a string, and `[0]` is appended to the end of the string.

---

You can see details of the operators at [About_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7).

See [About_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7) for how to create a variable including cases with special characters even if that doesn't directly apply here.

Comment: That was it. I'll go with the Sub-expression operator method. Thanks for the quick response!